# JQuery Load functions producing unexpected results

Tags: php, jquery, load

To follow on from a previous question here is a function used to determine what elements selected by Radio Buttons and Checkboxes are loaded on the right hand sign and what elements are loaded out via 'blank2.html'. The problem is it is loading the wrong elements in at the wrong points in time. Here is the code.

```
function product_analysis_global() { 
$(':checked').each(function() {
    var alt = $(this).attr('alt');
    var title = $(this).attr('title');
    if ($('#product_quantity_PRI_' + alt).attr('title') != title) {
        $('#product_' + alt).load(title); 
        $('#product_quantity_PRI_' + alt).attr('title', title); 
        $('#product_quantity_PRI_' + alt).val($(this).val()); 
    } else if ($('#product_quantity_PRI_' + alt).attr('title') != 'http://www.divethegap.com/update/blank2.html') { 
        $('#product_' + alt).load('http://www.divethegap.com/update/blank2.html'); 
        $('#product_quantity_PRI_' + alt).attr('title', 'http://www.divethegap.com/update/blank2.html'); 
    } else return false ; 
});
```

}

Take a look at its implementation here and you will see precisely what I mean.
http://www.divethegap.com/update/diving-trips/adventure-training and the click on BEGINNERS to load in the form.

I believe the problem lies in the $(this).attr('alt') and $(this).attr('title') collecting only one attribute for the box checked not all of them.

An additional feature that I would like this code to have is to treat a disabled checkbox or radio button at an unchecked box and load it out via 'blank2.html'

Answer (score 1):

`$.load` fires off an asynchronous request, therefore subsequent statements will be evaluated *before* the request finishes (at least in the vast majority of cases).

You will need to do what you want within its `success` callback, to ensure that it is *guaranteed* to happen once `$.load` has completed:

```
// make sure you make the current context available within the callback
var that = this;
$('#product_' + alt).load(title, function() {
        $('#product_quantity_PRI_' + alt).attr('title', title); 
        $('#product_quantity_PRI_' + alt).val($(that).val()); 
});
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I put this code inside a Ready function assuming that it would act like a callback function. It didn't. I am a but new to JQuery and as much as I appreciate your help and need a few more instructions on what exactly I should be doing. The other thing that I would like to ask as well is that this booking system is very slow at loading in the content. Are there better alternative.s

Comment: @Robin Knight - Sadly, if it takes the booking system a lot of time to build up the response then there is nothing you can do about that on the client side - besides indicate to the user, by way of a loading message or a spinner that something is happening.